# Suma de valores y mostrar el resultado en una tabla relacionada

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas MySQL, la primera con un id, nombre y la segunda con un id (relacionado con el id de la primera tabla) y un valor.
Necesito hacer una consulta que sume todos los valores con un mismo id de la tabla 2 y lo muestre en una nueva columna de la tabla 1, en la fila de su id relacionado.

Tabla 1:

```
id  |  nombre
1   |  silvia
2   |  maria
3   |  pedro
```

Tabla 2:

```
id  |  valores
1   |  4
1   |  7
2   |  51
2   |  6
3   |  9
3   |  14
```

Resultado deseado:

```
id  |  nombre  |  valores sumados
1   |  silvia  |  11
2   |  maria   |  57
3   |  pedro   |  23
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes que joinear las tablas y agruparlas por los datos que quieres. Así puedes usar las funciones de agregación como SUM, AVG, etc.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT a.id, a.nombre, SUM(b.valor)
   FROM tablanombres a LEFT JOIN tablavalores b ON a.id = b.id 
   GROUP BY a.id, a.nombre
```

Comment: Genial, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: de nada colega!

Comment: Excelente Me sirvió para lo que necesitaba.... Gracias
mi resultado final... [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exeqM.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exeqM.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

```
select tabla1.nombre, sum(tabla2.valor) from tabla1, tabla2 where id_tabla1 = id_tabla2 group by tabla1.nombre, tabla2.valor
```

Te podría servir así sin usar `joins`